# how to set account lockout threshold (account lockout policy) in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there a way to set the account lockout threshold programmatically using C# ? I checked doc from Microsoft but no info about that. I tried NetUserModalsSet function to set the account lockout threshold but seem like not working. Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy stores Account Lockout policy settings in GptTmpl.ini file on domain controller located at

\DC1\SYSVOL\sysvol\amber.local\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit

where {31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9} is a policy ID.

One way to set the policy is to update the file with the following lines under the [System Access] section

```
LockoutBadCount = 5
ResetLockoutCount = 30
LockoutDuration = 30
```

Then increment the versionNumber attribute of the policy being changed on the same domain controller (in Active Directory) using LDAP. Then run gpupdate /force command to replicate the change to other domain controllers.

The Active Directory part of group policy object is stored at CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=domain,DC=com

The solution is pretty much complex and there is a bunch of code you will have to write.